# PHP the if never happens

Tags: php

I'm adding data from a MySQL database to an array, but the program doesn´t start the if´s

```
$nextPhotoID = array_map(function ($p) {
    return $p['id'];
},$nextPhoto);

if ($_GET['id'] != $nextPhotoID[count($nextPhotoID) -1]){
    $right = $nextPhotoID[array_search('id', $nextPhotoID) +1]; 

-- $right is undefined variable, latter in code, where i need to write it

}
if ($_GET['id'] != $nextPhotoID[0]){
    $left = $nextPhotoID[array_search('id', $nextPhotoID) -1];
}

-- same with $left
```

Why is it undefined variable? I don´t understand it at all. My SQL is working.

Comment: If the condition evaluates to false then `$right` is never set and therefore undefined.  Similar for `$left`.  If your logic requires them to be set in all cases then set them to a default value.

Comment: what should they have as default value? their id?

Comment: Since it appears this code is allowing a user to cycle through a list of photos (to left or to right) it seems a good default for `$right` would be `$nextPhotoID[count($nextPhotoID) -1]` (keep selecting right-most) and similar for `$left` (set to `$nextPhotoID[0])` - I would expect your UI would not allow "moving beyond" limits but this would handle it in any case.

Comment: If i set it, it only takes the default value

Comment: Well then, as mentioned above, that must be because your `if` statement never returns true. We don't know what data you've got so we can't tell you precisely why that is - you'll need to debug it

Comment: i have data from mysql database, i have ids, names, type of the file. I tried var_dump on everything, and everything returns data, but the variables from if didn´t

Comment: Ok. So then please provide a [mre] of the issue, then we can help more easily

Comment: I had problem in the SELECT, but thanks anyways